# angular-ui-router nested states doesn't work with multiple views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Trying to make nested views work, but can't understand where i'm doing wrong. I have parent view with navigation and content, and when user click navigation links, it should load correct view. For some reason it still shows default content.

There are separate login and error states with views, but i removed them to make example simpler.

Here is plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/bvcNzDwSanPkVm1zASVe?p=preview

So when user click on link, he should see template of selected state loaded to unnamed ui-view.

Comment: I understood how state works :) with your before after plunkers. Thank you for your question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it solved. I have to put additional ui-view to default view:

```
'': {
      template: '<div ui-view></div>'
    },
```

Here is working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/zy4mYR?p=preview